# Specify Publish timeouts in mass transit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, timeout, publish, masstransit

Is there a way to specify timeout value when publishing messages using the MassTransit Library. How to handle scenarios when message broker goes down. Now it seems that Publish call waits indefinitely. It would be nice to control these behavior. Should we rely on cancellation token? Timeout implementation might be better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass a `CancellationToken` to `Publish`. If canceled, an `OperationCanceledException` will be thrown. If you want to use a timeout, you can create a `CancellationTokenSource` with a timeout.

```
using var source = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

await bus.Publish(message, source.Token);
```

Comment: If you use a CancellationTokenSource  with timeout, when timeout occurs will masstransit throw OperationCanceledException  after configured timeout-time?