# MassTransit failing publish configuration

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I wonder what would be the appropriate way to configure MassTransit for failing Publish() if the message broker (RabbitMQ in this case) is down?

Comment: Commonly asked, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562077/specify-publish-timeouts-in-mass-transit).

Comment: Thank you very much, @ChrisPatterson! I really appreciate it!