# MassTransit handle Publish exception

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

I'm using an IHostedService in order to Publish a list of events to RabbitMQ, using MassTransit.

I now wanted to handle exceptions on Publish, when for example RabbitMQ is not available.
Then my idea is to mark the db row relative to the message to be sent with Error = 1, TransientError = 1, so that next time it will be tried to be sent again.

Here is how I configure MassTransit

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Host(new Uri(_configuration["RabbitMQ:URI"] + _configuration["RabbitMQ:VirtualHost"]), $"ENG {_configuration["Application:PlantID"]} Producer", h =>
        {
            h.Username(_configuration["RabbitMQ:UserName"]);
            h.Password(_configuration["RabbitMQ:Password"]);
        });

        cfg.Publish<UpdateNorm>(x =>
        {
            x.Durable = true;
            x.AutoDelete = false;
            x.ExchangeType = "fanout"; // default, allows any valid exchange type
        });

        cfg.ConfigurePublish(x => x.UseExecute(x => 
        { 
            x.Headers.Set("SiteID", _configuration["Application:PlantID"]); 
        }));


    }));
});


//OPTIONAL, but can be used to configure the bus options
services.AddOptions<MassTransitHostOptions>()
    .Configure(options =>
    {
        // if specified, waits until the bus is started before
        // returning from IHostedService.StartAsync
        // default is false
        options.WaitUntilStarted = false;

        // if specified, limits the wait time when starting the bus
        //options.StartTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        // if specified, limits the wait time when stopping the bus
        options.StopTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

        
    });
```

And here my IHostedService implementation

```
public class MessageBrokerQueueBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<MessageBrokerQueueBackgroundService> logger;
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint;
    private readonly int MessageBrokerQueueCheckMillis;
    private readonly DB db;
    private readonly BLMessageBrokerQueue blMessageBrokerQueue;

    public MessageBrokerQueueBackgroundService(
        DB db,
        BLMessageBrokerQueue blMessageBrokerQueue,
        IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint,
        ILogger<MessageBrokerQueueBackgroundService> logger,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.db = db;
        this.blMessageBrokerQueue = blMessageBrokerQueue;
        this.publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
        this.logger = logger;
        this.MessageBrokerQueueCheckMillis = Convert.ToInt32(configuration["MessageBrokerQueueCheckMillis"]);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        logger.LogDebug($"MessageBrokerQueueBackgroundService is starting.");

        stoppingToken.Register(() =>
        {
            End(stoppingToken);
        });

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ICollection<MessageBrokerQueue> messageBrokerqueueList;
            try
            {
                messageBrokerqueueList = await blMessageBrokerQueue.GetMessageBrokerQueueListAsync();

                foreach (var element in messageBrokerqueueList.OrderBy(x => x.PK))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (element.Context == "Norm")
                        {

                            await publishEndpoint.Publish<UpdateNorm>(new
                            {
                                element.Key1,

                            }, stoppingToken);
                        }
                        // define other contexts
                        else
                        {
                            throw new MessageBrokerQueueUnknownContextException($"Unknown Context: {element.Context}", element.Context);
                        }

                        await blMessageBrokerQueue.MessageSentAsync(element);
                        logger.LogInformation("MessageBrokerQueueBackgroundService Message Context: {Context}, Key1: {Key1}, Key2: {Key2}, Key3: {Key3} correctly Published.", element.Context, element.Key1, element.Key2, element.Key3);
                    }
                    catch (MessageBrokerQueueUnknownContextException e)
                    {
                        logger.LogError(e, "MessageBrokerQueueBackgroundService unknown Context: {Context}.", e.Context);
                        await blMessageBrokerQueue.MessageNonTransientErrorAsync(element, $"Unknown Context {e.Context}");
                    }
                    //catch (Exception Rabbit not available e)
                    //{
                    //    logger.LogError(e, "MessageBrokerQueueBackgroundService Generic Exception threaded as transient");
                    //    await blMessageBrokerQueue.MessageTransientErrorAsync(element, e.Message);
                    //}
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        logger.LogError(e, "MessageBrokerQueueBackgroundService Generic Exception threaded as NOT transient");
                        await blMessageBrokerQueue.MessageNonTransientErrorAsync(element, e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.LogError(e, $"MessageBrokerQueueBackgroundService error while processing queue.");
            }
            finally
            {
                await Task.Delay(MessageBrokerQueueCheckMillis, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }

    protected Task End(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        logger.LogDebug($"MessageBrokerQueueBackgroundService background task is stopping.");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I tried to Publish with Rabbit shut down, but this method hang forever

```
 await publishEndpoint.Publish<UpdateNorm>(new
 {
     element.Key1,
 }, stoppingToken);
```

until I restart Rabbit, then it continues and finishes correctly.

I want to avoid to wait indefinitely. My idea was to wait for some seconds and then mark for this exception the error as transient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562077/specify-publish-timeouts-in-mass-transit

Comment: Thank you for your fast help. Any way to undestand whether it was canceled due to RabbitMQ inactivity? Thanks and bye

Comment: If it's canceled, it's because the broker was unavailable. Otherwise, it would have sent it within milliseconds.

Comment: indeed.. thanks again, have  a nice we